# Why I am getting negative values

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int notes[4] = {2000,500,200,100};
    int stocks[4] = {2,5,5,5};
    int notesC[4] = {0};
    int n;
    printf("Enter amount\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i<4; i++){
        if(n>=notes[i]){
            if(stocks[i]>=0){
            notesC[i] = n/notes[i];
            n = n - (notes[i] * notesC[i]);
            stocks[i] = stocks[i] - notesC[i];
            }
            else{ 
            notesC[i] = n/notes[i+1];
            n = n - (notes[i] * notesC[i]);
            stocks[i] = stocks[i] - notesC[i];  
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Number of notes utilised are\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
         printf("notes[%d] : %d   stocks[%d] : %d\n", i, notesC[i], i, stocks[i]);
    }
}
```

In this program, after taking input = 6000, the expected output is

notes[0] = 2 stocks[0] = 0 
notes[1] = 4 stocks[1] = 1 
notes[2] = 0 stocks[2] = 5 
notes[3] = 0 stocks[3] = 5

But instead of the above output, I am getting,

notes[0] = 3 stocks[0] = -1 
notes[1] = 0 stocks[1] = 5 
notes[2] = 0 stocks[2] = 5 
notes[3] = 0 stocks[3] = 5

My condition is, when stocks[i]  are zero, use the remaining stocks. But I am not getting the logic for the same.
Any help regarding the same would be appreciable.

Comment: `if(stocks[i]>=0)` --> `if (stocks[i] > 0)`.

Comment: @user3386109 I have tried it, it is not working, thank you

Comment: Yes, that's because you're computing `n/notes[i]` and not taking into account that `stocks[i]` might be less than that number.

Comment: @user3386109 If you can share the working program with the modifications you are telling, it would be thankful

Comment: strongly suggest: write a loop/for( int n=0; n<6000; n++ ) rather than inputting 'n' from the user.  Then step through the program.  Very soon, you will notice that 'n' becomes negative and the program never ends

Comment: Why are you expecting notes[0] = 2? The way I see it, if n = 6000 it will hit the line saying notesC[i] = n / notes[i] which means notesC[0] = 6000 / 2000 = 3

Comment: If n/notes[i] > stocks[i] it must goto notes [i+1] and use up all the stocks of notes[0]